# Change value in an array

Tags: php, mysql

I am import from a CSV to Mysql, every works fines the only problem is i have to convert normal date to mysql date. can anyone help.

```
$row = 1;
if (($handle = fopen($_FILES['Filedata']['tmp_name'], "r")) !== FALSE) {
    while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 10000, ";")) !== FALSE) {  
        if($row != 1) {
            $sql = sprintf('INSERT INTO %s ('.$fields.') VALUES ("%s")',
              'flight_tbl',
              implode('", "', array_map('mysql_escape_string', $data))
            );          
            mysql_query("SET names latin5");            
            mysql_query($sql);
        }
        $row++;
```

Comment: Can you describe your "normal date format"?

Comment: sane indentation always helps. as well as posting *relevant* code and *data*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean this?

```
$data[$your_date_field_index] = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime($data[$your_date_field_index]));
```

Comment: Yeah Thanks dear!
$data[3] = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($data[3]));

Answer (score 1):

Since you don't define "normal date" this is not guaranteed to work, but if your date is held in a string the answer will almost certainly be:

```
$mySqlDate = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime($normalDate));
```

And if it is an integer Unix timestamp, it will be:

```
$mySqlDate = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', $normalDate);
```

Comment: $data[3] = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($data[3]));